# Is there a way to make HTTP request headers immutable?

Tags: security, web

There are various ways the web applications can be attacked using the vectors in HTTP request itself. Attacks like the HTTP response splitting make use of modifying the request headers itself to exploit the vulnerable applications. Apart from input validation and sanitization at the server side, the question came to my mind if one can make the request headers immutable.

Is it possible to make it immutable?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking but if you are sending your request over https you have certain level of confidence that you got what client sent.  But again -- completely not clear what that buys you.

Answer (score 3):

Request headers are sent from the client to the server.

The browser itself constructs an HTTP request to send. A user with control over the client can of course change the HTTP request, including headers to anything that they want.

Therefore, making them immutable is impossible. Remember, as a general rule, anything on the client-side is up for grabs.

You can prevent headers from being altered during transit. That is, while the HTTP request is on the wire from the client to the server. For this, a technology called TLS is used (used to be called SSL, and most of the time it still is). This encrypts and authenticates the connection, making it immutable.

You can see if TLS/SSL is being used because the browser address bar will display HTTPS at the very beginning of the URL.